# Can reverse proxy for both grpc and grpc-web with envoy?

Tags: proxy, dns, grpc, envoyproxy, grpc-web

I have grpc server, web application and mobile application. With web application, I used envoy proxy for reverse from grpc web to grpc server by my domain. But this only grpc web can connect to my server over envoy, my application run with grpc cannot connect it. I want to connect to my gprc server over my domain with both grpc-web and grpc. Any one can help me explain and solve this issue. Thanks every one

This is my envoy setup

```
admin:
  access_log_path: /tmp/admin_access.log
  address:
    socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 9901 }

static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: listener_0
    address:
      socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 9090 }
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          codec_type: auto
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local_service
              domains: ["*"]
              routes:
              - match: { prefix: "/" }
                route:
                  cluster: echo_service
                  timeout: 0s
                  max_stream_duration:
                    grpc_timeout_header_max: 0s
              cors:
                allow_origin_string_match:
                - prefix: "*"
                allow_methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
                allow_headers: keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout
                max_age: "1728000"
                expose_headers: custom-header-1,grpc-status,grpc-message
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.grpc_web
          - name: envoy.filters.http.cors
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
  clusters:
  - name: echo_service
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: logical_dns
    http2_protocol_options: {}
    lb_policy: round_robin
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: cluster_0
      endpoints:
        - lb_endpoints:
            - endpoint:
                address:
                  socket_address:
                    address: server
                    port_value: 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the exact question? Currently you need to use Envoy to translate grpc-web to grpc.